# Xpages Build process and Replication

Tags: xpages

I'm wondering if someone can enlighted me a little bit on the Xpages build process and how this works with other replica copies of a database.  Much of the advice I've seen posted regarding working with the the Domino Designer indicates (logically), that you'll have much faster response working on local copies and then replicating those to the server.

I'll usually save my changes locally, build manually, and replicate to the server, and most of the time, that seems to work fine.  However, on some occasions, I've found that when I view the work I've done in the browser on the server copy, it hasn't seemed to update... in fact in a couple of scary incidents, it displays a version from several weeks ago (where is it even getting that from??).  This isn't a browser caching issue, and I've opened the design elements (xpages, custom controls) on the server copy and verified that the changes ARE there.  I end up having to perform a Clean on the server copy (not just a build) of the application, and then it displays as expected.

This seems like a foolish question, but you shouldn't have to perform a build on each replica copy correct?  Any thoughts as to what might be an issue here?  There is another developer involved, and he works directly on the server as he's in the same location, but we are rarely working at the same time, and never on the same elements.  We are not using source control at this time.

Comment: Hi, this is not a foolish question. Me and my coleagues have seen this behaviour as well. We lost a few days work because of this unfortunatly

Comment: Are you sure nobody else opened your database in designer? Especially with autobuild flag? Designer keeps cached design as eclipse project, so in that case you need to Refresh your application, what fetches design elements from NSF (designer doesn't refresh itself if change is replicated to your local NSF). Without refresh incremental build won't compile newer elements.

Answer (score 2):

We have seen similar behavior ourselves.

In our case, we do development on a server, clean / build project and then copy that database as a template to a deployment server. From there, we update design in the production database.

We have noticed that build process sometimes fails, especially when working over slower links. So we always repeat clean / build / refresh process a couple of times and we try to do it while in office with fast connection between the work stations and the server.

We haven't experienced build problems lately, so this repeating of build process obviously helps.

We have also seen that replicating design between local and server copies sometimes causes build related problems, which could explain the problems you are seeing. We have stopped using replication because of that and are now always working on the server copy directly.

I don't think that your not-using of source control software has anything to do with it.

Comment: I agree.  Updating the final design to production isn't really the issue, it's the updating of the design in your development environment as your developing that's the issue; as you make modifications and test them you constantly have to build.  A 5 second build on a local copy could take several minute doing it against a server copy if you're connecting over the internet, and I've got FIOS; it's pretty quick. I wish there was a way to initiate a build from the Server Admin client on a database or something of that nature.  Thanks for the tip on doing the clean/build twice; sounds prudent.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do all changes inside local template, then perform "Project \ Clean", then update design in server database. It works in 99% of cases. If not, I perform "Project \ Clean" once again. I hate this, but looks like it's the only way to get consistent code on production.

Comment: So are you saying you do a Design Replace from the local template to update the design to the server?  You find that is faster than doing a build on the server?  Also how to you test your design changes locally?  The problem with the local replica copy is that the ACL is consistant with that of the server, and so when you try to preview locally, it insists that you have to have your Default/Anonoymous entry in the ACL set to Author or above.  Using a template would get around that problem, so that's an interesting alternative.

Comment: it's definitely faster and more reliable. I'm not testing design changes locally, just because in most cases I do need the full server infrastructure with various users registered. Usually server contains the right ACL settings, when the template ACL just has a couple of entries with full access rights.